# Absolute value and inequality in integral

Tags: calculus, integration

In I proof I saw this inequality

$$
\int_0^x u'(y) \, dy \leq \int_0^x |u'(y)| \, dy
$$

Why is this true? Is it also true without the derivative? Shouldn't it be a absolute value sign on the left hand side?

Comment: Yes, this is true without the derivative. This is because $|u(y)| - u(y) \ge 0$, and so $\int_{0}^{x} |u(y)| - u(y) \ge 0$.

Comment: Note that if $x$ is real, then $x \le |x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f,g$ are Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f \leq g$ on $[a,b]$

then $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx.$$

Comment: So $f(x) \le |f(x)|$

Comment: Thanks! I saw this inequality, but is it true in my case? $f$ and $g$ are two different functions but in my inequality it is the same function, $u$, on both side.

Comment: Well let us pick  $y \in [0,x].$ $u'(y)$ could perhaps be positive, 0, or even negative.   But $|u'(y)|$ is always nonnegative.  In the case $u'(y)<0,$ then $|u'(y)|>0,$ so $u'(y)<|u'(y)|.$ In the case $u'(y)=0,$ then $u'(y)=|u'(y)|=0,$ and in the case $u'(y)>0,$ we have $u'(y)=|u'(y)|>0.$ Thus, in any case $u'(y) \leq |u'(y)|$ and assuming Riemann integrability of both, what you say is true.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically speaking, you can see the integral as the positive/negative area between the curve of a function and the x-axis.

So, given $f$, the integral of $|f|$ will be greater (in the same interval).